# Python 3.7 and PyGILState_Ensure() (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, gil, python-3.7

I have a Windows routine that uses the Python Library.  I started out with 3.6.5 and a static library.  Got it to work.  Moved to a .dll Python library.  Also works.  Moved to 3.7.  Does NOT work.  It hangs when I attempt to close the embedded Python with a call to PyGILState_Ensure() and then Py_Finalize().  It hangs on the call to PyGILState_Ensure().

So I backed off a bit and went with Python 3.6.6.  This also works.  Same code, just a different library.  Has anyone else noticed a change in behavior of the GIL stuff for Python 3.7?  In the documentation, they mentioned they made some changes with the GIL.

Comment: I will try to post sample code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.6 and below you need to call PyEval_InitThreads() You no longer have to do this in python 3.7, Py_initialize() does it for you. Could be your problem?

Comment: I don't call that.  Only calls I make before Py_Initialize() are:  Py_IsInitialized(), Py_GetPath(), Py_SetPath(), and PyImport_AppendInittab().  [PyImport_AppendInittab() calls PyModule_Create(), but I don't think it worked even when I took out the call to PyImport_AppendInittab().]

Comment: Oops, looks like Py_GetPath() should not be called before Py_Initialize(). I wonder if that is new...

Comment: You should call PyImport_AppendInittab() then py_Intialize